# Handling date-agnostic events with Moment.js and FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to use FullCalendar since it's a fairly advanced and comprehensive library.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
{
   "classes":[
      [
         {
            "name":"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
            "days":"MWF",
            "times":"02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
            "crn":"11215"
         },
         {
            "name":"ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
            "days":"W",
            "times":"09:00 am - 10:50 am",
            "crn":"11216"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

The dates in my events are date agnostic. They do however have two keys:

`days` - These come in the format of `MTWRF`, each are chars for each individual day of the week

`times` - The time span with a `from` and `to`

I know the Moment.js library can handle dates, but I am totally lost on how I could deal with dates that are of this format.

This is what I have so far:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: false,
            weekMode: 'liquid',
            handleWindowResize: true,
            weekends: false,
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

            events: [{
               // add JSON data here..
            }, {
               // add JSON data here..
            }]
        });
```

Here is a JSFiddle of the weekly view:

http://jsfiddle.net/pLodk6oz/1/

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: what about the events that you're passing?

Comment: @Sushil That is the part I am not sure what to do with, since the day of the weeks follow this `MWF` format for Monday, Wednesday, Friday.

Comment: hmm.. have you tried the `eventRender` event?

Comment: I have not. I am looking at the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) right now. How would this help me format the date objects?

Comment: i was trying this yesterday. perhaps this can help as well http://jsfiddle.net/h9cC6/2084/

Comment: what you can do is make your events array a global array and in the `addEventSource` event, create dates based on your days. I've added a file called `date.js` which will tell u what day it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87410/discussion-between-thegreencabbage-and-sushil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're getting the days as single letters i.e. **MWF** for Monday, Wednesday, Friday i would suggest you to create a global `dataset` and use that in the `AddEventSource` event

declare the global dataset like this.

```
var myDataset = {
        "classes": [
            [{
                "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
                "days": "MWF",
                "times": "02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
                "crn": "11215"
            }, {
                "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
                "days": "W",
                "times": "09:00 am - 10:50 am",
                "crn": "11216"
            }],
            [{
                "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture",
                "days": "MWF",
                "times": "02:00 pm - 03:20 pm",
                "crn": "11215"
            }, {
                "name": "ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab",
                "days": "F",
                "times": "02:00 pm - 03:50 pm",
                "crn": "11217"
            }]
        ]
    };
```

you can then use the `addEventSource` event to wire up your custom dates.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',
        function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/46tnzj72/4/)**

**EDIT:** *I will not take the credit alone. I was using the `addEventSource` method with 3 parameters since my version of fullCalendar was old which was failing for **@theGreenCabbage**. he found that the new version takes an extra parameter which is the `timezone` and after updating that it works fine.*

Comment: Thank you SO much for the help Sushil.